# Angular JS resizing an element when a textarea resizes

Tags: html, angularjs, resize

I am building a directive for writing and previewing comments similar to that of Github comments (conversations). My directive has two HTML elements, a textarea and a div (using angular-marked). What I like to do is to resize my div when I resize my textarea. I have scanned this site and googled a lot but no pure angular solution was satisfactory.

Below is my directive simplified:

```
    .directive('obibaCommentEditor', ['$log', '$timeout',
  function($log, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        comment: '='
      },
      template: '<div><tab><textarea id="message" ng-model="comment.message"></textarea></tab><tab><div id="preview-message">{{comment.message}}</div></tab></div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        function findChild(el, targetId) {
          var children = el.children;
          for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.id && child.id === targetId) {
              return child;
            }
            return findChild(child, targetId);
          }
        }

        $timeout(function() {
          scope.message = findChild(elem[0], 'message');
          $log.debug(scope.message.offsetWidth);
          resize();
        });

        //get preview element
        var previewElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#preview-message'));

        function resize() {
          var dim = {
            width: scope.message.offsetWidth + "px",
            height: scope.message.offsetHeight + "px"
          };
          $log.debug(dim);
          previewElement.css(dim)
        }

        //Add the "mousemove" event to check, perhaps you can change the event "mouseup"
        elem.on("mouseup", function() {
          resize();
        });
      }
    };
  }
])
```

And its template:

```
<form class="obiba-comment-form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="send()">
  <tabset>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li>
        <a href="//guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/" target="_blank">{{'comment.markdown-doc-link' | translate}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <tab heading="{{'comment.write' | translate}}">
      <textarea id="obiba-comment-form-message" ng-model="comment.message" class="form-control obiba-comment-form-message"></textarea>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="{{'comment.preview' | translate}}">
      <div class="obiba-comment-marked" marked="comment.message">
      </div>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
  <button ng-if="onCancel" ng-click="cancel" type="submit" class="btn btn-default obiba-comment-form-submit">
    <span>{{'cancel' | translate}}</span>
  </button>

  <button ng-disabled="!comment.message" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary obiba-comment-form-submit">
    <span>{{'comment.send' | translate}}</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

I thought I had found a solution but in my case there is no way of setting the height of the marked element. In my simple test in plunker, I had played with ng-mouseup to set the height of the marked to that of the message. In my directive the same code never returns the proper height (undefined) nor offsetHeight (0). So the general question is how on earth do we modify DOM elements in pure AngularJS? I read most of the docs and could not find a descent way without timers, etc to change height of an element.

Well, if you have looked at the Github comment section and know how to do the same in Anhgular, please share the approach.

EDIT2:

This is the crapy solution I found:

```
.directive('obibaCommentEditor', ['$log', '$timeout',
  function($log, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        comment: '='
      },
      template: '<div><tab><textarea id="message" ng-model="comment.message"></textarea></tab><tab><div id="preview-message">{{comment.message}}</div></tab></div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        function findChild(el, targetId) {
          var children = el.children;
          for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.id && child.id === targetId) {
              return child;
            }
            return findChild(child, targetId);
          }
        }

        $timeout(function() {
          scope.message = findChild(elem[0], 'message');
          $log.debug(scope.message.offsetWidth);
        });

        //get preview element
        var previewElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#preview-message'));

        function resize() {
          var dim = {
            width: scope.message.offsetWidth + "px",
            height: scope.message.offsetHeight + "px"
          };
          $log.debug(dim);
          previewElement.css(dim)
        }

        //Add the "mousemove" event to check, perhaps you can change the event "mouseup"
        elem.on("mouseup", function() {
          resize();
        });

        resize();
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Please notice that the code is based on the code provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074519/wzvang

Cheers.

Comment: you mean only to resize or also consider the text length?

Comment: Only resize. If you go to Github and try to comment on a committed file you'll see what I mean. When user resizes the message, the preview window also changes size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element size of the preview in Github is changed when you click on the "Preview" tab, here I created a similar directive:

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])

.directive("resizeTextarea", [function(){
    return function(scope, elem, attrs){

        //save current size of textarea
        var current = {width: elem[0].offsetWidth, height: elem[0].offsetHeight}

        //get preview element
        var previewElement = angular.element(document.querySelector(attrs.resizeTextarea));

        function resize(){
            previewElement.css({width: current.width + "px", height: current.height + "px"})
        }

        //Add the "mousemove" event to check, perhaps you can change the event "mouseup"
        elem.on("mousemove", function(){

            //detect if the textarea has not the initial size
            if(this.offsetWidth != current.width || this.offsetHeight != current.height){
                current = {width: this.offsetWidth, height: this.offsetHeight};
                resize()
            }

        });

        resize()
    }
}]);
```

```
<tab>
    <textarea resize-textarea="#preview-message" ng-model="comment.message" class="obiba-comment-form-message"></textarea>
</tab>
<tab>
    <div id="preview-message">{{comment.message}}</div>
</tab>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FA0LPMOfmRnESMj8MfrI?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. In my case both elements (message and preview) are inside the directive making the matter a little more complicated. I have a hell of a time finding the elements dimensions via Angular (no jQuery). For instance the message offsetHeight/Width is always undefined even if I use a $timeout. I tried to play with your example and had no luck. May be you have a go at it with the two elements inside the directive. Cheers.

Comment: I found this crapy solution and I hope somebody can sexify it (see EDIT2). The only thing I like about it is that it's pure Angular and I won't get complaints about 'document' when use grunt (jshint).